# How does speed of sound change when you extract air out of the experiment?

Tags: acoustics, vacuum

So I understand that pressure and density cancel each other out so speed of sound is mostly related to the temperature of the gas.

But I was wondering what exactly, experimentally happens with the speed of sound while you are extracting air out of a tube towards a vacuum. Does it stay the same and then suddenly drop to zero near the vacuum?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Transmission of Sound Waves in Gases at Low Pressures](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/sp958-lide/069-072.pdf) and the reference therein.

Comment: Everything can be found on wikipedia of course. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound#Speed_of_sound_in_ideal_gases_and_air

Comment: Thanks for the link but I cannot find the part about what exactly happens with the speed of sound when pumping a gas to vaccuum.

Answer (score 2):

> So I understand that pressure and density cancel each other out
> so speed of sound is mostly related to the temperature of the gas.

You are right. In air the [speed of sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound#Speed_of_sound_in_ideal_gases_and_air) is given by
$$v=\sqrt{\gamma\frac{p}{\rho}}$$
where $p$ is the pressure, $\rho$ is the density,
and $\gamma$ is the adiabatic constant of air ($=1.4$).
According to the kinetic theory of gases this expression is a constant
(only depending on temperature and the average mass of the air molecules).

> what exactly, experimentally happens with the speed of sound
> while you are extracting air out of a tube towards a vacuum.
> Does it stay the same and then suddenly drop to zero near the vacuum?

When you reach vacuum, then the equation above equation becomes
$$v=\sqrt{\gamma\frac{p}{\rho}}=\sqrt{\frac{0}{0}}=?$$
which is undefined. It is not $0$, not $\infty$, and nothing
in between. Such a result was to be expected.
In vacuum there is no sound, because there are no molecules
carrying any sound.
When there is no sound, then it doesn't make sense asking
for the speed of this sound.

Even before reaching the absolute vacuum, there are so few
air molecules in your container, that they rarely collide
with each other. And when the mean free path between two
collisions becomes longer than the wavelength of sound,
then the concept of sound waves is not applicable anymore.

Comment: Very nice explanation, thank you for that. Does that mean though that speed of sound is constant up until that point where the mean-free-path between the collisions of the particles becomes longer than the wavelength (obviously there won't be a specific value for which this suddenly happens)?

Comment: @ZaellixA Yes, the speed of sound pretty much stays constant,
up until that point where the sound disappears.

Comment: So if I understand correctly the speed of sound is does not change but at some point (when mean free path>wavelength) you cannot measure any sound anymore and thus not speak of this concept anymore

Comment: @bananenheld Yes, this is what I meant to say.
But actually it is still an oversimplification, and reality is more complicated.
For more details see the article linked by Farcher below your question.